# How can I run OpenGL programs in MonoDevelop (Linux)?

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, monodevelop, glut, ubuntu-11.04

I want to run OpenGL ,GLUT, FreeGlut, GLEW libraries in MonoDevelop on my Ubuntu machine.
I will be coding my programs in c++ or c# . I have already installed the libraries of the above from my package manager. 
Also I know how to use OpenGL in gcc so there is no need for such answers.
If not possible then recommend me an IDE for OpenGL programming.
Thanks.

Comment: And, what exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to run Opengl libraries (e.g. glut) using c++ in the MonoDevelop IDE

Answer (score 0):

I've found [a link](http://www.mono-project.com/Libraries#3D_and_Games_Frameworks) where you can found info **about some OPENGL libraries for MonoDevelop.**
I hope that it will be useful.

Regards

Comment: Link-only "answers" are non-answers and discouraged in SO. If the remote site ceases to exist, then this post will be even less useful. You should aim to make your answers as self-contained as possible, so you should at least summarize the contents of the remote link.